# How to import com.android.location.provider?

Tags: android, location-provider

How I can import `com.android.location.provider` for creating custom unbundled location provider?
I use android studio and I import .jar file but it doesn't work .
in java code I wrote :

```
import com.android.location.provider.LocationProviderBase;
```

but It makes error and compiler can't reference to the library .

Comment: That is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Yes I know . where is it ? I should add a .jar file?

Comment: "where is it ?" -- [in the platform](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/location/lib/java/com/android/location/provider/LocationProviderBase.java). "I should add a .jar file?" -- I am skeptical that this class will be useful to you.

Comment: I want to create a unbundled location provider like UnifiedNLP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. Library `com.android.location.provider.LocationProviderBase` is not in public android API which is implemented in android.jar and can not be used easily.For referencing to this library you should use reflection in java and linking process occurs at runtime.

OR

You should get source of this package and manually add it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up Google Play services.

Follow following link to set up the google play service:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Add following lines to you gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
    }
```

You can use following links for further information:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: I don't want to use google service for location provider . I want to create my own network location provider like UnifiedNLP